# d3.select.attr only working with some attributes when called from a hover action

Tags: css, d3.js

I'm trying to get an action to work when I hover over a table row. What I want is for the table row to turn gray, the stroke of the chart that corresponds to that table row to turn red with a width of 5, every other stroke to turn gray.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
var paths = d3.selectAll("path");

var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this)
        .style("background-color","gray");

        //this works
        d3.select(paths[0][i]).attr("stroke-width", 5);

        //this sets them all to gray
        d3.selectAll("path").attr("stroke", "gray");

        //this doesn't work???
        d3.select(paths[0][i]).attr("stroke", "red");

     });
```

My thought was to first turn them all gray, then turn the individual one to red.  For some reason, changing the stroke attribute on just one of the paths doesn't work, but changing the stroke attribute on all the paths works and changing the stroke-width attribute on just one of the paths works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: instead of `attr` try `style`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.  Why is that when the one for selectall uses attr?

Comment: I posted it as a answer. please check this one as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836757/whats-the-difference-between-selection-style-and-selection-attr-in-d3-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `.style()` instead of `.attr()`

```
 d3.select(paths[0][i]).style("stroke", "red");
```